# Loginview control asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been searching and haven't got luck, I got a tutorial to use the loginview control in order to display or hide parts of the views to different user roles in my application. The thing is that the tutorial I've found is for ASP.NET and I've been told by one of my colleages that it is the same framework for ASP.NET MVC but the way to use it is different. Have you got any good tutorial to recommend?

EDIT: I've got all my application set up, and the login and the roles already configured (via asp.net membership provider). This is all already running. The thing is that if I have role a and role b I want role a to be able to actually see the links to the actions it is authorized to work with, and not b for example. If in the Index of my application I've got a link to "Edit" and only the role a can access to the action, then it will be displayed just for logged in users that belong to role a, and not to those who belong to role b

Thank you,
Vikitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?id=77

And remember to use [Authorize] attribute on your contoller Actions to prevent users accessing sensitive views.

Comment: No, I've got all my application set up, and the login and the roles already configured. This is all already running. The thing is that if I have role a and role b I want role a to be able to actually see the links to the actions it is authorized to work with, and not b for example. If in the Index of my application I've got a link to "Edit" and only the role a can access to the action, then it will be displayed just for logged in users that belong to role a, and not to those who belong to role b

Comment: Oh right. I'm thinking you'll need to set up a custom helper for your ActionLinks/RouteLinks that checks if user is Authorized - if not return a blank string. How does that sound?

Comment: I just found what I needed, it is just a matter of getting the role of the user logged in and showing the link depending on an if clause...It was much more simple than I expected. Thanks for answering :D